# webdesign on laptop screens? Top elements seem darker than bottom

Tags: css, colors

I mainly work with a laptop. My question is if I should worry about the fact that the same colors look darker on top such as the menu bar but lighter on the bottom such as the footer. The colors are the same, rgb(60,60,60).

Is it because my screen is cheap or is it due to my choice of colors? On my HP envy or tablets etc it looks great.

Comment: Best thing you can do it test on multiple devices.  You will always encounter issues with screens do to different user settings and burnout from the screens.

Comment: To explain, keep in mind that different screens always render colors slightly differently from each other and the angle of vision also affects this. However this question is not formulated in the correct format: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Luca I will reevaluate my question. Also thank you for your comments.

Comment: How could you counteract this effect on some monitors but not all? This is the responsibility of the owner of the device. What you can still do (and should) is to be sure that there is a sufficient contrast ratio between background and text color for each information provided by each page (buttons, text, text in images, etc). This is not only related to [accessibility](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G18.html) but also usability. Tools like Color contrast Analyzer and [Tanaguru Contrast Finder](http://contrast-finder.tanaguru.com/?lang=en) will be your friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this link](http://www.qualitylogoproducts.com/lib/why-monitors-display-different-colors.htm)

There are just too many reasons to explain why screens color things differently.

Some of these include:

- rgb color settings
- age of screen (older screens may 'burnout', or 'not be vibrant')
- screen type
- viewing angle
- type of screen (LED,LCD,etc).

This is the reason the likes of most 'new' games actually ensure you calibrate your screen before playing them ("Please alter screen until logo is barely visible") - this is up to the user/client to decide, not you as a developer (although this 'setting' could be useful, but possibly overkill ;)).

Even with using the same make and model of screen, there may/will still be differences in colouring. 
It's just a fact of computing I'm afraid.

So, the bottom line is, no, I wouldn't worry about it. the best thing you can do is ensure you use a good color scheme (not similar colours), and this *should* allow even the oldest of screens to work happily enough with your websites/etc.